# Android Annotation Working of @IdRes

Tags: java, android

I was using `setId` method of `View` class. According to this method

```
public void setId(@IdRes int id) // This will accept resource id
```

When I tried to use this method with some hardcoded `int` value(let say 100), then this method start throwing correct warning which is expected-

```
actionButton.setId(100);
```

> Expected resource of type id.

But when I converted this hardcoded value into a method and never defined that this method will return `@IdRes`, Warning gets silent.

```
    private int getViewId() {
        return 100;
    }
```

Method call to set Id.

```
 actionButton.setId(getViewId());
```

Isn't both are same. Hardcoded `int` and a `int` return from this method. So why in one case method throwing warning and in another it gets silent.

For a sake I tried with `StringRes` but I am getting warning in both cases.

```
 private void setMyString(@StringRes int resourceString) {}
```

Warning in both below cases-

```
    setMyString(1);
    setMyString(getStringId()); getStringId returns int value
```

Comment: I think the @IdRes annotation forces you to use a resource id rather than a literal int. Resource id can be assigned to a variable

Comment: Yes I agree @Inducesmile but in a case of StringRes, it never throw warning in both cases

Comment: Are you running lint or using Android Studio's (IntelliJ IDEA's) built-in data flow analyzer?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA's

Answer (score 7):

It is just a Lint **warning** since the method expects a variable to be from R.id class.

Regarding the case of value returned from a method, Lint doesn't bother to check the whole function whether it is returning a hardcoded integer or an actual id.

From the documentation of @IdRes it states:

> Denotes that an integer parameter, field or method return value is
>   expected to be an id resource reference (e.g. android.R.id.copy).

Also the annotation just exist in the source code for documentation. After the code is compiled, the annotation will be removed.

Comment: This isn't a case, I tried with StringRes and what method returns surely matters. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Well, it seems @StringRes also expects the return statement of the mehtod to be from the class `R.string`. But again, just a warning!

Comment: Yes I agree with you Nabin its a lint warning, but currently I am trying to figure out logic behind that. Why StringRes throw error and IdRes isn't. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The same happens to View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE and View.VISIBLE. Warnings and warnings, even if you do a int getStateForView(){return View.INVISIBLE;} and set it on a View.

Answer (score 2):

In one case (`@IdRes`) you are calling a method from the API (`View.setId()`),
while in the other, you are calling a method in your own code.
Also `getViewId()` is not annotated, so it is not obvious from the signature what kind of int it returns.

With the following methods :

```
private int getUndefinedRes() {
   ...
}

private @IdRes int getIdRes() {
   ...
}

private @StringRes int getStringRes() {
    ...
}

private void setMyString(@StringRes int resourceString) {
}

private void setMyId(@IdRes int resourceId) {
}
```

The lint and inspection results are (as of Android Studio 2.3.3) :

```
    // API method with definitely wrong value (constant)
    // --> ERROR
    new View(context).setId(100);
    new TextView(context).setText(100);

    // API method with definitely wrong value (from method declaration)
    // --> ERROR
    new View(context).setId(getStringRes());
    new TextView(context).setText(getIdRes());

    // API method with potentially wrong value
    // --> ok
    new View(context).setId(getUndefinedRes());
    new TextView(context).setText(getUndefinedRes());

    // own method with potentially wrong value
    // --> ERROR
    setMyString(getUndefinedRes());
    setMyId(getUndefinedRes());
```

It seems that the lint only looks at the method signature.

It is also more lenient when you call an API method : it shows an error only if it is obvious that you are doing something wrong.
I think that it's because doing otherwise would force everybody to add a lot of annotations.

On the other hand, when you add annotations in your code, you are opting in for the additionnal severity.

Comment: No I didn't override any method setId(), I am using setId method of View only. Case which you mentioned at last -> setMyId(getUndefinedRes()); // this method is not throwing any error which is my concern.

Comment: I think that in both cases (int or string) it has nothing to do with overriding, but whether you are invoking a method from the Android API or from your own code.

Comment: bwt, thank you for looking into this, But I am not calling any method from Api. Both methods are written in my java file

Comment: `actionButton.setId()` (`View.setId()` actually) is an API method invocation

Comment: Hello downvoters, care to explain ? I sincerely don't understand what is wrong with this answer